# Linking actions on two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry the title isn't very descriptive, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I am making a website that handles student group funding requests. A particular request for funding could involve any number of items. I have two tables: requests and items. A group begins a request by filling out a "request" form, which contains a brief summary of the request, a category (speaker, advertising, etc.), and some other fields necessary for the bureaucratic process. That works fine and was handled pretty much entirely by scaffolding. The problem I'm having is with the "items". I would like the user to click the "submit" button on the new request form and be taken to another page at which he can add any number of items to the items table, all containing in a field the id of the request he just submitted.

The front end appearance doesn't really matter - it could all be on one page - what's important is that the user submits information to one table and then submits information to a second table, with the info sent to the second table containing something that connects it to the information just submitted to the first table.

As you can probably guess, I'm pretty new at rails (I went through the book Head First Rails and I'm working on my first project), so I'm looking for a general explanation about how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read / watch this tutorial. It is quite good.

UPDATE:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but those tutorials are very outdated

Comment: Yep, but I found the most recent one, see update. It worked for me, just mixed up them.

Comment: I built my solution based on this on rails 3.